# Populating columns of a SQL table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm in the process of creating an application that allows users to search a large database. To improve the application I'm writing a script that inserts only unique values of the large database into a new, smaller database that will take less time to search.

Here is the PHP script I'm currently working with. I'm using plain text files that contain only the unique values from each column, with one file representing each column. I had already written a script to export SQL columns to text files so I decided to reuse it for this proof of concept. I use a similar script to generate a file containing the column names.

```
$column_names   = file_get_contents('./column_names');
$columns        = explode("\n", $column_names);
foreach($columns as $column_name){
  if($column_name != ""){
    // Get the text file with unique values from a column
    $data_file = file_get_contents('./data/' . $column_name);

    // Add a new column to the database
    mysql_query("ALTER TABLE test_db.$tmp_table ADD $column_name varchar (60)");

    // For each value from the file, insert that value into the database
    foreach (explode("\n", $data_file) as $data) {
      // Skip blank values and the initial meta-data
      if(($data != "") && ($data != $column_name)) {
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO test_db.tmp_table (" . $column_name . ") 
                     VALUES (" . $data . ")");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This code produces a new database that looks similar to this

```
+--------+------+-------+
| Name   | ID   | Value |
+--------+------+-------+
| James  | NULL | NULL  |
| Jim    | NULL | NULL  |
| NULL   | 1    | NULL  |
| NULL   | 2    | NULL  |
| NULL   | 3    | NULL  |
| NULL   | NULL | 42    |
+--------+------+-------+
```

My goal is to have the columns be independent from one another so that I perform an infix search of a value on each column with the following PHP script.

```
$columns = mysql_query("SHOW columns FROM test_db.tmp_table");
// Value to be searched, from HTML
$id =  $_GET['id'];
if($id != ""){
  while ($col = mysql_fetch_array($columns))
  { 
    $col[0];
    // Print the result
    print_r(
      mysql_fetch_array(
        mysql_query("SELECT `$col[0]` 
                     FROM test_db.tmp_table 
                     WHERE `$col[0]` 
                     LIKE '%$id%' 
                     LIMIT 0, 100")));
  }
}
```

I'd like to produce a table that looks like the following table so that I can search it using the above query.

```
+--------+------+-------+
| Name   | ID   | Value |
+--------+------+-------+
| James  | 1    | 42    |
| Jim    | 2    | NULL  |
| NULL   | 3    | NULL  |
+--------+------+-------+
```

How should I go about creating an intermediate database in which the columns are independent, similar to the above table? I'm worried I may be approaching the problem of searching a large database the wrong way.
Thanks for taking the time to read all this!

tl;dr How can I create a database that looks like the second table, not the first.

Comment: what does the file at ./column_names look like?

Comment: alter table tmp_table  add unique (name, id, value) ?

Comment: Do you actually have a performance problem here? Properly indexed databases can be searched extremely quickly by a database engine. Profile the performance first. When you've done that, think about creating your tables directly in  SQL instead of slowing things with intermediate text files. This looks like a solution looking for a problem, and your approach to solving it seems overly convoluted.

Comment: @Bryan ./column_names is a text file that has the name of each column and then a new line.

Comment: @MikeW The real database has about 50,000 rows and around 50 columns, performing the infix search on it direction takes a good deal of time. In the near future I will create the tables directly in SQL, I'm only using the text files because I already had a script to create them and I wanted to get this proof of concept going.

Comment: @b.b3rn4rd the text files already have the unique values. I'm trying to insert them into a new database without each column occupying a unique set of rows.

Comment: @Jacthoma 50 000 rows is tiny it is nothing for MySQl. I have seen MySQL query 250 000 000 rows in seconds. Why dont you post the current table structures here and also the query that is so slow. I bet you are missing a index or something like that.